Download Excel Files from OneDrive using msal and oauth2 from Enterprise Drive
I have been trying to download an excel file that is located in an Enterprise One Drive. To do so, I registered an application in azure to obtain client and tenant id and client secrets in order to authenticate the access. The authentication seems to work well, but once I try to download the excel file, all I get is the url from the site, and I have not been able to solve this.
I have searched on many places, but a lot of them work only for personal OneDrive accounts are used not to access and download the files, or use username/password authentication.
Could someone help me?
So far this is my code:
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication
import requests

client_id = "MY_CLIENT_ID"
client_secret = "MY_CLIENT_SECRET"
tenant_id = "MY_TENANT_ID"
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"
scope = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
drive_id = 'MY_DRIVE_ID'
item_id = 'MY_ITEM_ID'

app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id,
    authority=authority,
    client_credential=client_secret,
)

token_response = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
access_token = token_response['access_token']


url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/items/{item_id}"
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
item_details = response.json()

import requests

# Build the API endpoint URL to access the download URL of the item
url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/items/{item_id}"

# Set up headers with the Authorization token
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}

# Make the GET request to access the item's details
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
item_details = response.json()

# Check for errors in the response
if 'error' not in item_details:
    # Extract the download URL from the response
    if '@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl' in item_details:
        download_url = item_details['@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl']

        # Download the file content using the download URL
        file_response = requests.get(download_url)
        if file_response.status_code == 200:
            file_content = file_response.content

            file_name = 'downloaded_file.xlsx'

            # Write the file content to a file
            with open(file_name, 'wb') as file:
                file.write(file_content)
            print(f"File downloaded successfully: {file_name}")
        else:
            print("Failed to download file")
    else:
        print("Download URL not found in item details")
else:
    print("Error accessing item:", item_details['error']['message'])

